# Output of a "git pull" what does this change mean?

Tags: git, version-control

I never understand the change output to the screen can someone please give me the following meaning of the follownig change in dummy terms

```
**Fast-forward
 build.number       |    4 ++--**
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you have file called `build.number` in your git repository, and somebody else has changed that file upstream.

Fast-forward means when you ran `git pull` to get changes, your tree was untouched - you did not do any commits of your own, and thus git pull was able to update your repository without necessity to do any merges. It simply set your local branch pointer to be exactly the same as on server - this is exactly what fast-forward means.

Comment: Also, the `4 ++--` part indicates that 4 changes were made, which consist of two lines added (`++`) and two deleted (`--`). Since `git` by default notices changes at a line level (not words/characters), that probably indicates only two lines changed, with the originals deleted and the replacements added, but it could have been the first two lines deleted and two more added at the end as well... Note also that the number of `+/-` characters don't always exactly match the number of changes when you have a more complex change - they're a relative scale...